# Memory Leak of autoreleased NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I have profiled my code and the profiler shows that one of my methods is leaking memory on objects that are autoreleased. Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```
-(void) fillRSSEntriesDictionaryObject: (NSMutableDictionary *) dictionaryObject  withAllRSSEntries: (NSArray *) allRSSEntries forKey: (NSString *) keyForRSSEntriesArchive {
    RSSEntry *anRSSEntry;
    NSArray *source;
    NSMutableArray *episodes;   
    NSMutableArray *sourceArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil] autorelease];
    for (int i=0; i<[allRSSEntries count]; i++) {
        source = [allRSSEntries objectAtIndex:i];   // grab the next source array.
        episodes = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil] autorelease];  // initialize the episodes array
        for (int j=0; j<[source count]; j++) {
            anRSSEntry = [source objectAtIndex:j];
            NSDictionary *episodeDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:anRSSEntry.blogTitle, @"Blog Title", 
                                               anRSSEntry.articleTitle, @"Article Title", nil];
            [episodes addObject:episodeDictionary]; // save the info for this episode
        }

        [sourceArray addObject:episodes];
    }

    // Finally, we need to create the key-value pair for the source array
    [dictionaryObject setObject:sourceArray forKey: keyForRSSEntriesArchive];
}
```

As you can see, sourceArray and episodes are the only alloc'd memory and both are autoreleased. The episodes array is added to the sourceArray array. The sourceArray becomes the object that is passed to the caller.

The specific information provided by the profiler is that the responsible library is "foundation" and the responsible caller is +[NSDictionary (NSDictionary) newWithContentsOf:immutable]. When I expand this, it eventually points to my app as the responsible library and this method as the responsible caller.

Since these are autoreleased arrays, why is the profiler complaining about leaked memory?

Comment: why is this tagged C++?

Comment: sorry, I just accepted the suggestions without much thinking

Comment: Does it point to any line of code in the right tab?

Comment: @hybridcattt no, how do you get the profiler to show a line number. I am using Instruments for profiling. Not sure what you mean about a right tab?

Comment: I took that method and added it to a blank project and made it compile. The static analyzer didn't throw any warnings so I guess the problem is coming from somewhere else and it's causing a leak in that method.

Comment: unrelated, but you might consider adding an @autoreleasepool{} to that  loop.

Comment: @JeffB6688 Yes I am talking about Instruments too. Select leak line that you want to investigate, open right panel in the Instruments (it's called Extended Detail). You will see a stack trace for this leak. Double click on desired function and it will show the responsible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no leak here. Most likely some other code later uses these objects and leaks them.

You can use Instruments to see the retain/release history of the leaked objects, which should help you find the extra retain or missing release.